# Azure Pipeline build fails

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a solution that has 3 projects in it.Two of them are .Net Standard project and one is a .Net Framework project which is Unit Test. I am trying to build it but I get an error.

```
 C:\Program 
 Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208,5): Error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\src\TestIOC\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208,5): Error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\src\TestMvvm\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

This is my current Azure Pipelines YAML file.

```
trigger:
- master

pr:
- master

variables:
  buildConfiguration: Release
  buildPlatform: Any CPU
  coreSolution: 'src\TestMvvmCore.sln'
  coreCSProj: 'src\TestMvvm\*.csproj'
  testCSProj: 'src\TestMvvm.Tests\*.csproj'
pool:
    vmImage: vs2017-win2016

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '4.9.1'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln, src\TestMvvm.Tests\packages.config'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: Build TestMvvm Solution
  inputs:
    solution: '$(coreSolution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    restoreNugetPackages: true
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me fix the error

Answer (score 3):

Since your project type and **msbuild** task would not call `dotnet restore` automatically, it need execute another task to call it explicitly. You can try with execute [dotnet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) task instead of `nuget restore` before execute `msbuild xxx.sln` .

In addition, you can also add `/t:restore` into MSBuild Argument to call `dotnet restore` explicitly:

```
msbuildArguments: ‘/t:restore’
```

Note: In **msbuild** task,`restoreNugetPackages` has been deprecated now. It will not work any more and you must use task to achieve restore package.

Comment: Liang:  tried it, but does not work.  Gets an error:  Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.

Comment: I ended up udating my test project to .net core to get it working

Comment: Hi, since you have got the solution. Do you mind share it as answer here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to restore your nuget package first, and you have to supply with SLN file, not with the packages.config.

Your NugetCommand@2 task should only restore a solution file, not restoring `packages.config` file. Correct your YAML first.